# A basic question on sigma algebra, probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have an algebra $F_0$ consisting of subsets of $\Omega$ and the sigma algebra generated by it $F=\sigma(F_0)$. suppose $A \subset \Omega, A \subset B, B \in F $. Can we find a sequence of sets $\{A_n\} \in F_0$ such that $A \subset \cup A_n $ and $P(B) \geq \sum_n P(A_n)$. Hint Enough.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @Did: I don't know. Any element in an algebra can be characterized in terms of the generating set, but sigma algebra can't be. I am not sure whether we can find a sequence of disjoint sets in algebra sandwitched between $B$ and $A$. May I know the reason why it is downvoted. Is it too trivial ?

Comment: Why are you asking me? I did not downvote yet. If I had, it would have been for the absence of personal input.

Comment: @Did: Anyways, is the statement true ? I am not sure.

Comment: @aaaaaa Did you look at my hint?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you try to cover the rationals that lie on $[0,1]$ with half-closed intervals $(a,b]$ you will always end up covering an extra $(-\epsilon, 0)$.

Second Hint: Now take for example a normally distributed random variable. It induces an absolutely continuous probability $P$ in $\mathbb R$ (w.r.t. Lebsegue measure). Let $F$ be the Borel sets which are generated by the algebra of half-open intervals $F_0$, let $A$ be $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ and $B=[0,1]$.